# Cant give php array a value using a variable

Tags: php, arrays, variables, null, return-value

Ive been stressing alot with this php code and cant figure out why it does not work.. Stack overflow is kind of the my last resort.
First things first, here is my code:

```
$avar = "Name";
$args = array(
            'category_name'    => $avar
        );
var_dump($args);
```

This code returns:

> array (size=1)
>     'category_name' => null

So the question is, why doesnt it return "Name" instead of null and is there any way to give the array the value of the variable?

Please help me!

** Update **

Im sorry. Forgot I had the code inside a function. Here is the code I use. I put it inside a brand new document, and it still doesnt work. Only difference is now i get an error. (Im coding for wordpress, and i guess some warnings are disabled in order to tighten security). The code:

```
<?php
    $avar = "SomeText";
    function theFunction() {
        $args = array(
            'category_name'    => $avar
        );
        var_dump($args);

    }
    theFunction();
?>
```

The code still works with strings.

Comment: Can't reproduce it - this code is ok, problem is somewhere else...

Comment: [Works for me](https://eval.in/436184)

Comment: PHP version you are using?

Comment: Works perfectly [fine for me here](https://eval.in/436186)

Comment: Make sure you are testing the right file, maybe you have duplicates.

Comment: Is that really all your code? https://3v4l.org/J3vHI You're not setting the array in a function are you?

Comment: @user2267097 You are most likely hiding your actual code. If you want us to be of any help, you need to provide us with complete code.

Comment: Im sorry.. I updated the code.
Yes, the code is inside a function.

Comment: Time to read about function scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    $avar = "SomeText";
    function theFunction() {
        global $avar;
        $args = array(
            'category_name'    => $avar
        );
       var_dump($args);

    }
    theFunction();
?>
```

Comment: Your $avar variable is not reachable by the function. You can declare it in side the function, or use the global option as in my example, or you could pass it to the function `function theFunction($avar) {...` and `theFunction($avar);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!
Problem was messy code.. Function was inside another function inside a class. You got me on the right track. :)